# 'Hide Snippet By Default' option is not working with a mouse click

Tags: bug, stack-overflow

On Stack Overflow if you try to add a code snippet the last option with a checkbox on the left labeled as `Hide Snippet By Default` isn't clickable with the mouse when using
full view. There is a minor line on it that does not allow clicking with the mouse, although you can click on the checkbox above it and press `tab` and then press <kbd>spacebar</kbd> to select it. See the below image.

[image]

If you press <kbd>F12</kbd> and open developer tools the option is suddenly clickable and the line is gone which is preventing it from being selected when clicked. See the image below:

[image]

Which is because there is a separator between these checkboxes options and the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button below which somehow slides up on the last checkbox and prevents it from being clicked. See the image below; you can monitor it by zooming the web page using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + MousewheelUp.

[image]

INFO

- OS Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr)
- Browser Mozilla Firefox Quantum 64-bit